# How to loadFromJSON a canvas with a fabric.Group?

Tags: javascript, json, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to save my canvas as a JSON and load this later. ToJSON and loadFromJSON are working well in fabricjs, except when the canvas have a group. Anyone can explain how to do this?

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail the issue you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Current version 1.5.0 has a bug about group initialization (which is used in loadFromJSON), and there has been a pull request in github to fix it.

Therefore, next version, it will be fixed. If you need soon, v1.4.13 dose not have a bug about it.

Comment: If there are path objects inside a group, there are also bugs.
If not, I need more detail information.